# continuity test for multiple variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image][image]
In question 3 as it is given in the hint with that substitution the limjt dies not exist. Similarly why cant we put in question 4 the substitution y^2 = -x^2 +mx^4 . This way it becomes dependent on m and hence its limit does not exist. Correct me if I'm wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution in the first case works only if the substitution is of even power or else it does not work like in the second case